# Sort a multilevel orderdict in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict of type OrderDict as follows:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d=OrderedDict()
>>> d['a']=(dict({'key1': 40}))
>>> d['a'].update(dict({'key2': 10}))
>>> d
OrderedDict([('a', {'key1': 40, 'key2': 10})])
>>> d.values()
odict_values([{'key1': 40, 'key2': 10}])
```

Now, I am trying to sort the created orderDict by the values of the dict, i.e., 10 and 40, but seems it keeps sorting by the keys. Here is what I am doing:

```
>>> sorted(list(d.values())[0], key=lambda x: x[1])
['key1', 'key2']
```

I am looking to get this:

```
{'a': {'key2': 10, 'key1': 40}}
```

Comment: As an aside, `d['a'].update(dict({'key2': 10}))` -> `d['a'].update({'key2': 10})` ->  `update(key2=10)` ... but *really* this should just be `d['a']['key2'] = 10`

Answer (score 1):

In order to sort a dictionary by value, use `d.get` as the sort key:

```
{k: d[k] for k in sorted(d, key=d.get)}
```

Comment: Thanks wim. Here is what I get when running it: >>> {k: d[k] for k in sorted(d, key=d.get)}
{'a': {'key1': 40, 'key2': 10}}

Comment: Much neater than my answer, gj!

Comment: @AlexMan In your case you would need `d['a'] = {k: d['a'][k] for k in sorted(d['a'], key=d['a'].get)}`.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you're looking for is this:

```
{k: v for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])}
```

This is the equivalent of list comprehension for dictionaries

Comment: Thanks, but seems it is not giving me the right answer. Here is what I am getting: >>> {k: v for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])}
{'a': {'key1': 40, 'key2': 10}}